# Problema em PHP Undefined variable

Tags: php

Eu estou estudando PHP por uma apostila que achei na net e ela pediu pra digitar um código mas depois que eu digito não da erro e nem mostra qual foi o resultado que deveria escrever o conteúdo do array na tela.

> "Undefined variable: producs in C..."

eu fui na parte superior do código e digitei 
`if(isset($_POST['products'])){` e coloquei o fecha chaves la em baixo mas não adiantou, não mostra nada de erro e nem o resultado.

```
$products = array(array('TIR', 'tires', 100),
                          array('OIL', 'oil', 10),
                          array('SPK', 'spark plugs', 4));

    echo '|'.$products[0][0].'|'.$products[0][1].'|'.$producs[0][2].'|<br>';
    echo '|'.$products[1][0].'|'.$products[1][1].'|'.$producs[1][2].'|<br>';
    echo '|'.$products[2][0].'|'.$products[2][1].'|'.$producs[2][2].'|<br>';
```

Answer (score 3):

`echo '|'.$products[0][0].'|'.$products[0][1].'|'.$producs[0][2].'|<br>';`

Veja onde está `$producs[0][2]`.

Sua variável se chama `$products` - **PRODUCTS** e não **PRODUCS** (sem a letra **T**)

OBS: É sexta-feira!

Comment: arrumei, mesmo assim o erro persiste.

Comment: O mesmo erro ? Como ficou o código agora ?